# Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement Inserting into table using python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter

I am trying to commit data retrived from tkinter widgets into a SQL table (which has already been created and has the column names of leaderID, firstname,secondname,age,address,postcode,telephone,email). I keep receiving the error despite remaking the table, rewriting the SQL, resetting the database server etc. This code is contained within a function which is activated by a tkinter button. All of the inputted data is retrieved from each tkinter widget using the .get() syntax.

```
LeaderID=random.randint(1,10000)
print(LeaderID)
sqlcommand="INSERT INTO leaderinfo (leaderID, firstname,secondname,age,address,postcode,telephone,email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, &s, &s, %s)"
LeaderInput= (LeaderID,FName.get(),SName.get(),Age.get(),Address.get(),Postcode.get(),TelephoneNum.get(),Email.get())
mycursor.execute(sqlcommand,LeaderInput)
mydb.commit()
print("Completed Transaction")
```

Produces the error

```
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

Further I was wondering how I could make the code look a little more readiable, as you can see from the code their is quite a long line of code contain a lot of placeholder '%s', could I move those to a different line?

Let me know if you would like me to supply additional information.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `&s` instead of `%s` for some of your arguments. Fix it and you should be OK:

```
sqlcommand="INSERT INTO leaderinfo (leaderID, firstname,secondname,age,address,postcode,telephone,email) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
# Here ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------^---^
```

Comment: This should just be closed as a typo.

Comment: Sorry fellas, its ben a long night